# Installing Perf on Ubunutu 20.04.5 LTS

Tags: apt, kernel

I'm trying to install `perf` on my Ubuntu server.
To install `linux-tools`, I tried both `linux-tools-generic`, `linux-tools-generic-hwe-20.04-edge` and `linux-tools-5.15.0-69-generic` getting this error every time:

```
Unpacking linux-tools-common (5.4.0-146.163) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_5.4.0-146.163_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/perf', which is also in package linux-base 4.6
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package linux-tools-5.4.0-146.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-5.4.0-146_5.4.0-146.163_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-5.4.0-146 (5.4.0-146.163) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-tools-5.4.0-146-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-5.4.0-146-generic_5.4.0-146.163_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-5.4.0-146-generic (5.4.0-146.163) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-tools-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-generic_5.4.0.146.144_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-generic (5.4.0.146.144) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_5.4.0-146.163_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My kernel:

```
uname -r
5.15.0-69-generic
```

From my understanding, I'm trying to install `linux-tools-5.4.0-146` which is an incorrect version. I was not able to find this package for `5.15.0-69-generic`.

Any idea how I can get perf on my machine without upgrading to 22.04?

I saw that `linux-tools-5.15.0-69` is available on `jammy` but didn't manage to install it.

```
sudo apt-cache search linux-tools-common 
linux-tools-common - Linux kernel version specific tools for version 5.4.0
```

Any chance to find `linux-tools-common` for 5.15 somewhere?

Comment: Where did you get `linux-base 4.6` from? All current Ubuntu versions have 4.5. I suggest cleaning up your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, removing out-of-distro packages, then just install the linux-tools that matches your kernel.

Answer (score 0):

This look like a package conflict between the `linux-tools-common` package and the `linux-base` package.

Here is how you could solve that: first open a terminal then remove `linux-tools-common` with `sudo apt remove linux-tools-common` then install `linux-tools` with `sudo apt install linux-tools-generic`

Check that perf is installed and you are done `perf --version`

Comment: Is it safe to remove `linux-base`? It will also remove `brltty initramfs-tools linux-base linux-generic linux-generic-hwe-20.04
  linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic linux-image-5.13.0-40-generic linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic
  linux-image-5.15.0-67-generic linux-image-5.15.0-69-generic linux-image-5.4.0-146-generic
  linux-image-generic linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-modules-5.13.0-30-generic
  linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-56-generic
  linux-modules-5.15.0-67-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-69-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-30-generic` and a few others

Comment: It can render the system unstable so it is better to not do it if you dont know how to deal with that, I am gonna update my answer with a safer solution.

Comment: This does not work either. `linux-tools-generic` depends on `linux-tools-common` so it gets reinstalled everytime.